# command dahdi show channels not working on asterisk CLI

Tags: asterisk, trixbox

I'm using Trixbox 2.6 (Centos 5.5 Final, Asterisk  1.6.0.26-FONCORE-r78, FreePBX). I'm using Digium's TE110P PCI card where I plug my PRI line.

dahdi_tool is showing that the line is working. (No alarms)
when i run "service dahdi status", it show output like:

```
[trixbox1.localdomain ~]# service dahdi status
### Span  1: WCT1/0 "Digium Wildcard TE110P T1/E1 Card 0" (MASTER) HDB3/CCS/CRC4 
  1 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  2 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  3 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  4 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  5 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  6 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  7 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  8 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
  9 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 10 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 11 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 12 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 13 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 14 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 15 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 16 PRI        HDLCFCS      
 17 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 18 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 19 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 20 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 21 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 22 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 23 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 24 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 25 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 26 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 27 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 28 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 29 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 30 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)  
 31 PRI        Clear       (In use) (SWEC: MG2)
```

But when i run "asterisk -r" to goto astersik CLI and run "dahdi show status", it returns "No such command" error.

When i initially installed the trixbox system, "dahdi show status" command on astersik CLI was working fine and displaying the status. When I called the PRI line, the CLI was showing that a call is coming. But after a reboot, this issue came up that "service dahdi status" is showing the status but "dahdi show status" on CLI is not working. Also, now when I call the PRI line, I get a all-lines-busy-please-try-later message.

Can anyone help me understand what might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually mean dahdi can't load for one of any reason

1. (most likly) not configured propertly
2. Not compiled in
3. Really hard card error or card died.

For more info check output of following commands

```
lsmod |grep dahdi
dahdi_cfg -vvv
```

if not see issues, try do in asterisk cli

```
module unload chan_dahdi.so
core set verbose 3
module load chan_dahdi.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Dahdi channel is very sensitive to errors in configuration.  Check your chan_dahdi.conf for errors then unload and load chan_dahdi.so module.